# I am using Heroku with Chromedriver on a python flask app on a college (OSU (oregon)) server, "flip2" on Mobaxterm in a virtual environment

Tags: python, flask, heroku, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting an error in the heroku log: "'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see [https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home"](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home%22)

I tried running this line in the command line:

heroku config:set CHROMEDRIVER_PATH=/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/chromedriver and I got a different error: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/chromedriver'

as well as several other configurations giving me the original error including:

./chromedriver
chromedriver
/nfs/stak/users/croysdaa/361/chromedriver

as well as changing my python file, app.py to say:

```
GOOGLE_CHROME_PATH = '/app/.apt/usr/bin/google_chrome'
  CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/chromedriver'
  chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
  chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
  chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  chrome_options.binary_location = GOOGLE_CHROME_PATH
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

chromedriver is in my requirements.txt file, and it is in my current directory

Answer (score 0):

I edited the google chrome path and chromedriver path in heroku configs (can be done in terminal or at heroku.com) to the ones mentioned in the following two comments. Since I'm getting the path variables from Heroku and not locally, I use os.environ.get (and import os) to get the paths

```
  #GOOGLE_CHROME_PATH = '/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome'
  #CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = '/app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver'

  chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
  #chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-sever=socks5://127.0.0.1:0000')
  chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
  chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
  chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1200x600")
  chrome_options.add_argument("--window-position=0,0")
  chrome_options.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")

  # exception for if chromedriver crashes on launch
  try:
      driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"), chrome_options=chrome_options)
      except WebDriverException as e:
          print("\nChrome crashed on launch:")
          print(e)
          print("Trying again in 1 second")
          time.sleep(1)
          driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"), chrome_options=chrome_options)
          print("Success!\n")
      except Exception as e:
          raise Exception(e)
```